# It looks like pub.dartlang.org is having some trouble

Tags: dart

I was trying to download packages and run command `pub get` when the error `Connection closed before full header was received exit code 69`. So I tried to use VPN, because I thought it was because of my network. Then I saw this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2As3.png)

I don't have any anti-virus, so what do I do?

**NOTE:** I'm not using Flutter

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: dart_application_2
description: A sample command-line application.
version: 1.0.0
# homepage: https://www.example.com

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.5 <3.0.0'

# dependencies:
#   path: ^1.8.0

dev_dependencies:
  lints: ^2.0.0
  test: ^1.16.0
```

Comment: can you share your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: you can try "flutter clean" then "pub get"

Comment: @FatihaIMOUSSAINE Pubspec.yaml added. I'm not using Flutter

Comment: try running " flutter pub cache repair " then kill the dart process and run pub get again

Comment: @FatihaIMOUSSAINE I'm not using Flutter

Comment: Flutter is just a package of Dart language..